# How to prevent $scope.$destroy?

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-scope, preventdefault

I want to prevent $scope.$destroy event in my nested controller in my page. I see the `event` object in callback function has method preventDefault, but it's not working as I expect.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // don't working!
});
```

It is possible to prevent $destroy event?

[plnkr Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/O2oK8EUJTEQYPadLTlK1/preview)

Comment: Is that in your diretive?

Comment: By the way: Its always good to clean up your directives and listen to the `$destroy` event to clean up your event listener such as click events etc.

Comment: @LordTribual no, it is in my nested controller on my page.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it? Whats the reason for this?

Comment: @LordTribual I agree with you, but I want to prevent closing modal window by similar way. I don't want to place listener on click on close button in my markup, etc.

Comment: Maybe you try to create a Fiddle or Plunker and explain your original problem. People will probably come up with a solution that fits your needs. I could also take a look. A working example is always good.

Comment: I think you are not trying to do what you think you are trying to do... you have to wire upper to prevent your modal to close, not trying to cancel the destroy cycle. This is something you NEVER want to do. That's like asking a JVM GC to "please do not garbage this dead reference"...

Comment: @pierre-gayvallet Exactly! Thats what I have been trying to say :)

Comment: don't create new scope, use $rootScope.